# Arduino (C++) enviar variável para página em PHP

Tags: php, c++, arduino

Eu tenho o seguinte código em C++ no Arduino

```
int variavelemc;
variavelemc = 10;
```

E tenho o seguinte código em PHP

```
$variavelemphp = $_POST['variavelemc'];
```

Como eu passo a `variavelemc` para a `$variavelemphp` ?

## Informação Adicional

O Arduino está conectado a Internet.

O código em PHP está hospedado na internet.

Comment: Depende. Esse PHP está sendo servido por um servidor web, suponho, então terá que enviar uma requisição HTTP do arduino para o seu servidor web. Você poderia rodar o PHP via linha de comando e fazer uma comunicação serial.

Comment: Dada a edição colocando que o PHP está hospedado e o Arduino conectado à internet, existem [bibliotecas](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HttpClient) cliente HTTP que você pode usar para fazer uma requisição.

Comment: É viável uma implementação com MySql(salvar os dados em um banco) direta no Arduino? Ou você precisa necessariamente de parametros enviados para serem tratados em um script PHP?

Comment: @DarleiFernandoZillmer precisaria ser necessariamente em PHP, já que a conexão direta com o MySQL não é fornecida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando a biblioteca Ethernet

Inicializando

```
byte mac[] = { 0x00, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDE, 0x01 }; // RESERVED MAC ADDRESS
EthernetClient client;
```

No begin()

```
Serial.begin(115200);
if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP"); 
}
```

no loop()

```
    if (client.connect("www.*****.*************.com",80)) {
        client.println("POST /add.php HTTP/1.1"); 
        client.println("Host: *****.*************.com");
        client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
        client.print("Content-Length: "); 
        client.println(data.length()); 
        client.println(); 
        client.print(data); 
    } 

    if (client.connected()) { 
        client.stop();  
    }
```